# Problem on Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Show that

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{e^{(\log{ax})^\gamma}}{e^{(\log{x})^\gamma}} = 1$$
for all $a > 0$ and $\gamma \in (0, 1)$.

Update: Thanks to @Matthew Pilling and @sea yellow, I was able to solve it using their inputs and have posted an answer.

Comment: Is $\log$ the natural logarithm or has it any other base?

Comment: Yes, it is the natural logarithm.

Comment: @Patricio Technically, if the result is true for some logarithm with base $>1$, then it's true for all logarithms with base $>1$. With base $<1$ the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Can someone kindly let me know why did the question attract a downvote? I will try to keep this in mind in the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @avocado Probably because you didn't show your effort on this problem, which is written in the rules.

Comment: Have you considered a substitution $y=\log(x)$? Try this to help you get started. Feel free to edit your own work into the original post. You likely won't get any help if you don't show any work. (At least not from me anyway)

Comment: @MatthewPilling, thanks a lot for giving me a starting point. I will update my post after working on your suggestion.

Comment: No problem. We've all been stuck on math problems and have had no idea how to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{(\log ax)^{\gamma}}}{e^{(\log x)^{\gamma}}}$

Taking logarithm (base $e$) both sides

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \log\left(\dfrac{e^{(\log ax)^{\gamma}}}{e^{(\log x)^{\gamma}}}\right)$

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {(\log ax)^{\gamma}}-{(\log x)^{\gamma}}$

substituting $b = \log a$ and $y = \log x$

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} {(y+b)^{\gamma}}-{(y)^{\gamma}}$

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} y^\gamma\left(\left(1+\dfrac{b}{y}\right)^{\gamma}-{1}\right)$

using Taylor series expansion of $(1+x)^n$

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} y^\gamma\left(\left(1+\dfrac{f_1(\gamma)g_1(b)}{y} + \dfrac{f_2(\gamma)g_2(b)}{y^{2}} + \dots\right)-{1}\right)$

where $f_1, f_2, \dots$ and $g_1, g_2, \dots$ are some functions of $\gamma$ and $b$ respectively

$\implies\log L = \lim\limits_{y \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{f_1(\gamma)g_1(b)}{y^{1-\gamma}} + \dfrac{f_2(\gamma)g_2(b)}{y^{2-\gamma}} + \dots\right) = 0$

since $\gamma \in (0, 1)$

$\implies L = 1.$

Note: Thanks a lot @Matthew Pilling and @sea yellow for your inputs.